# Determine if an ElementFinder matches a locator

Tags: javascript, protractor

In Protractor, is there a way to determine if an ElementFinder could be found by a different locator than the one used? I can't construct a second ElementFinder from the locator and use `.equals` because the original ElementFinder might not be the first element found by the locator.

My current solution is to construct an ElementArrayFinder from the locator then use `.each` or `.filter` in combination with `.equals` but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it more succinctly with built-in functionality to avoid boilerplate or making my own function.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any rational reason why do you avoid writing own methods?
IMHO it's far better to .filter on ElementArrayFinder than for example using xpaths with :nth-of-type() selectors.
In Protractor you can find element by various finding elements (see: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy) - it also can come in handy.

Hope I helped. If not - please specify your problem.

Comment: I don't mind writing my own methods, it just seemed like the type of thing that might already be doable in a single function call or line of code with protractor.